# Keychain Password Removal Command

Tags: command-line, osx, cryptography

Looking for a little guidance on removing all instances of a generic password keychain by either the service (svce) or label string. I can do it once at a time but I sometimes have machines that have 15+. Here is how I am able to one at a time:

By string:

```
security delete-generic-password -s com.apple.network.eap.user.item.wlan.ssid.DEMO
```

By label:

```
security delete-generic-password -l DEMO
```

And attempting to remove all at once using the awk command:

```
security find-generic-password -s "DEMO" | \sudo awk '/svce/{system("security delete-generic-password -s DEMO")}'
```

Only removes one at a time =/

Comment: This *seems* like a question that could be answered by somebody who knows shell and `awk` very well, and doesn’t know keychain stuff — but you’re not providing enough background information.  Can you give an example of the output from `security find-generic-password -s "DEMO"` and clarify what commands you want `awk` to execute for you?  (And the first two commands need to be run under `sudo` also, don’t they?)

Answer (score 0):

If all passwords is generated by same creator try:

```
security delete-generic-password -c CODE
```

Or

```
security delete-generic-password -a ACCOUNT
```

You can also try wildcards

```
security delete-generic-password -s "*.*"
```